# How to give a HTML element in NetSuite an ID in DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I try to use jQuery to give the element value in NetSuite to test, but cannot find out the HTML DOM ID of some customized drop-down list. **Not the internal ID**.
E.g.

```
<input type="text" id="soid">
```

However some ID for the customized elements can be found, and some are not.
Can we add an HTML ID for the element in NetSuite?

Comment: No, you're not able to assign an ID to an element. What are you attempting to do that can't be done in a client script?

Answer (score 1):

are you trying to get the ID of this input field using JQuery?
If so just use `$('#soid').val();` Or to get the text in the field `$('#soid').text();`

Answer (score 0):

- Select a value on the dropdown
- Right click the dropdown and press INSPECT
- look for a hidden input with the similar ID to your dropdown with the class named `nldropdown`
- set THIS field manually using Jquery

We do this alot and there is not straightforward docs on it